# R Shiny img() on UI side does not render the image

Tags: r, shiny

I have a static image in the local folder I am trying to render in the Shiny UI and it does not work. Shows a broken image with a question mark in the middle.

```
ui <- fluidPage(img(src = 'imagefile.png', height = '100px', width = '100px'))
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: in addition to @jenesaisquoi's answer below, save your App in the same directory you saved your www folder and name your app "app.R"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the image in a folder called www in the same directory, so you have www/imagefile.png.  Then, call

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(img(src = 'imagefile.png', height = '100px', width = '100px'))
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyAppDir(".")
```

But, you probably want to be using `runApp` with a separate ui and server file.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Could not find it documented. Perhaps I missed it.