# How to put entire image location in tags$img of shiny package?

Tags: r, shiny

The following code for tags$img is:

- Working...when the image is stored in 'www' folder and src = "Rlogo.png"
- Not working...when entire path of the image is given

I need to put the entire location in one of my shiny app where the app.R file will be run from command prompt. Please help thanks..

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  box(
    tags$img(height = 100, width = 100,src = "Rlogo.png"),
    tags$img(height = 100, width = 100,src = "E:/myApp/www/Rlogo.png")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Think about it this way: do you *really* want to expose your entire local hard disk’s contents to the entire world when publishing a website? I doubt it. Therefore, you fundamentally *can’t* serve contents from arbitrary locations on your hard drive. They need to be within an agreed-on location that’s whitelisted by your web server app — the `www` folder in your example.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes.. I got your point.. So, do you know any solution where the app.R file will be run from cmd prompt and image will appear.

Comment: Got a alternative solution.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145275/single-line-code-to-run-r-code-from-windows-command-line/54291514#54291514

Comment: Alternative solution without using renderImage: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760656/r-shiny-img-on-ui-side-does-not-render-the-image)

Answer (score 3):

use `imageOutput` instead of `tags$img`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    box(
        tags$img(height = 100, width = 100,src = "Rlogo.png"),
        imageOutput('image')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$image <- renderImage({
            list(src = "E:/myApp/www/Rlogo.png",
                 alt = "This is alternate text"
            )
        }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```